# Rolling window and problem with slice indexing

Tags: python, pandas

I use this Python code to calculate CQ statistic for each year in my dataset:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time
from CrossQuantilogram import Bootstrap
import CrossQuantilogram
from CrossQuantilogram import LjungBoxQ

d1=pd.read_csv(r"...\sgold.csv")
d2=pd.read_csv(r"...\cgold.csv")
```

```
def CQBS_years(d1,a1,d2,a2,k=1,window=1,cqcl=0.95,testf=LjungBoxQ,testcl=0.95,
                all=False,n=1000,verbose=True):     
       
    startyear,endyear = 2010, 2019
    if window>1+endyear-startyear:
        raise ValueError("length of window must <= data range")

    cqres,yearlist=[],[(str(x),str(x+window-1)) for x in range(startyear,endyear-window+2)]    
    for start,end in yearlist:
        if verbose:
            print("Processing {}/{}   ".format(end,endyear),end='\r')
        cqres.append(CQBS(data1[start:end],a1,data2[start:end],a2,k,cqcl,testf,testcl,n,False))

    res,yearindex=[],[str(x) for x in range(startyear+window-1,endyear+1)]
    if all:
        for i in [[df.iloc[x] for df in cqres] for x in range(k)]:
            merged = pd.concat(i,ignore_index=True)
            merged.index = yearindex
            res.append(merged)        
    else:
        res=pd.concat(cqres,ignore_index=True)
        res.index = yearindex
    if verbose:
        print("Bootstraping CQ done      ")
    return res
```

```
%%time
CrossQuantilogram.CQBS_years(d1["day"],0.1,d2["day"],0.1,k=1,window=1,cqcl=0.95,testcl=0.95,all=False,n=1000,verbose=True)
```

While estimating the CQBS_years function, I get this error: "cannot do slice indexing on RangeIndex with these indexers [2010] of type str". I know this is related to the string type of date in my CSV files. But I don't know how to solve it.

The dataset is available at this link: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1PXyXP3AK8_KYxRYfZWO3VHzPPueG3FEF?usp=sharing Here is the source of the code: https://github.com/wangys96/Cross-Quantilogram Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that selecting data like this in pandas - `df['2010':'2010']`, requires the dataframe `df` to be indexed by dates.

Thus, you need to read the data, parse the column with dates as `datetime`, and set the index to that column. This can be achieved in one step:

```
d1=pd.read_csv(r"...\sgold.csv", parse_dates=[0], index_col=[0])
d2=pd.read_csv(r"...\cgold.cs", parse_dates=[0], index_col=[0])
```

Comment: Thank you. I did what you suggested. Now I get this error: "need at least one array to concatenate". The problem is in [start:end]

Comment: Ok, now I see where the real problem was - see the updated answer.